# StrongSwan on Amazon Linux with RADIUS

Tags: linux, centos, radius, strongswan

I'm trying to run strongSwan on an Amazon Linux instance with authentication against RADIUS but I receive an error when trying to start strongSwan

`charon[9518]: 00[CFG] RADIUS initialization failed, HMAC/MD5/RNG required`

To install strongSwan I ran

`yum install strongswan`

`# swanctl --version
strongSwan swanctl 5.7.1`

`# swanctl --stats
loaded plugins: charon pkcs11 tpm aesni aes des rc2 sha2 sha1 md4 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation constraints acert pubkey pkcs1 pkcs7 pkcs8 pkcs12 pgp dnskey sshkey pem openssl gcrypt fips-prf gmp curve25519 chapoly xcbc cmac hmac ctr ccm gcm curl sqlite attr kernel-netlink resolve socket-default farp stroke vici updown eap-identity eap-sim eap-aka eap-aka-3gpp eap-aka-3gpp2 eap-md5 eap-gtc eap-mschapv2 eap-dynamic eap-radius eap-tls eap-ttls eap-peap xauth-generic xauth-eap xauth-pam xauth-noauth dhcp led duplicheck unity counters`

```
cat <<EOF > /etc/strongswan/strongswan.d/charon/eap-radius.conf
eap-radius {
    load = yes
    nas_identifier = ${DNSNAME}
    retransmit_timeout = 30
    retransmit_tries = 1
    servers {
        primary {
            preference = 99
            address = ${RADIUSFQDN}
            auth_port = 1812
            secret = ${RADIUSPSWD}
            sockets = 5
        }
    }
}
EOF
```

Complete startup log

```
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 06[MGR] tried to checkin and delete nonexisting IKE_SA
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 06[IKE] unable to resolve %any, initiate aborted
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 06[CFG] received stroke: initiate 'pod'
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 05[CFG] added configuration 'pod'
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 05[CFG]   loaded certificate "CN=vpn.test.dev.poddev.naimuri.uk" from 'vpnserver.crt'
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 05[CFG] adding virtual IP address pool 192.168.250.0/24
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 05[CFG] received stroke: add connection 'pod'
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal strongswan[10484]: charon (10493) started after 60 ms
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal ipsec_starter[10484]: charon (10493) started after 60 ms
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[JOB] spawning 16 worker threads
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[LIB] loaded plugins: charon pkcs11 tpm aesni aes des rc2 sha2 sha1 md4 md5 mgf1 random nonce x509 revocation const
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[CFG] no script for ext-auth script defined, disabled
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[CFG] HA config misses local/remote address
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[CFG] loaded 0 RADIUS server configurations
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[CFG] loading RADIUS server 'primary' failed, skipped
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[CFG] RADIUS initialization failed, HMAC/MD5/RNG required
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[CFG] opening triplet file /etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/triplets.dat failed: No such file or directory
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[CFG] sql plugin: database URI not set
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[CFG]   loaded RSA private key from '/etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/private/vpnserver.key'
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[CFG] loading secrets from '/etc/strongswan/ipsec.secrets'
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[CFG] loading crls from '/etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/crls'
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[CFG] loading attribute certificates from '/etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/acerts'
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[CFG] loading ocsp signer certificates from '/etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/ocspcerts'
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[CFG] loading aa certificates from '/etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/aacerts'
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[CFG]   loaded ca certificate "C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3" from '/etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[CFG] loading ca certificates from '/etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/cacerts'
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[LIB] openssl FIPS mode(2) - enabled
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[CFG] PKCS11 module '<name>' lacks library path
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal charon[10493]: 00[DMN] Starting IKE charon daemon (strongSwan 5.7.1, Linux 4.14.72-73.55.amzn2.x86_64, x86_64)
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal ipsec_starter[10484]: Starting strongSwan 5.7.1 IPsec [starter]...
Nov 13 14:14:34 ip-10-0-0-218.eu-west-2.compute.internal strongswan[10484]: Starting strongSwan 5.7.1 IPsec [starter]...
```

Comment: How did you configure strongSwan to authenticate to RADIUS?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Added the config to the question

Comment: Try promoting the _hmac_ plugin by setting `load=-1` in `/etc/strongswan/strongswan.d/charon/hmac.conf`.

Comment: @ecdsa Still the same.

Comment: Ah, sorry, it's the other way around. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using OpenSSL in FIPS mode, which disables MD5 as that's not FIPS-approved.

While you do have both the *md5* and *hmac* plugins loaded, the latter is ordered after the *openssl* plugin, which still registers its own implementation of `HMAC_MD5_128`. This implementation can even be instantiated, as the plugin's HMAC constructor really only checks if there is a static `EVP_MD` instance for the given hash algorithm, which, unfortunately, is the case for MD5 even in FIPS mode. However, using that instance with `HMAC_INIT_ex()` later fails (what triggers the error is trying to set the key on the HMAC instance).

To avoid this you could either disable FIPS mode (via *charon.plugins.openssl.fips_mode*), or make sure that the HMAC implementation provided by the *hmac* plugin is used instead of that of the *openssl* plugin.

The latter can be achieved by modifying the *load* setting of either of these plugins in their respective config snippet in `/etc/strongswan/strongswan.d/charon` in order to either demote the *openssl* plugin (set it to a negative numeric value), or by promoting the *hmac* plugin (set it to a value > 1). After a restart, the plugin order seen in `swanctl --stats` should be changed accordingly, and the output of `swanctl --list-algs` should show that the *hmac* plugin is providing `HMAC_MD5_128`.

Comment: I took your idea of the FIPS and in the openssl.conf file there is an option to disable FIPS which I set to 0 and now it's loaded the RADIUS configuration. Thank you!